# SwiftUI Textfield: Meaning of the $ in front of a State-variable?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Example:

```
TextField("Enter your name!", text: $name)
```

What does the $-sign before the variable mean? It is used nowhere else this way.

Comment: It means it is a binding to the value of the name var. so when the text field is updated by the user it will update the value. And it is used all over in swift ui.

Comment: You should review this basic tutorial: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/  This `$` sign is used A LOT in swiftui.

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59616744/state-variable-sign-usage